# Switched from eclipse to android studio , android studio extremly slow

Tags: android, compilation

Whenever i run my app, it takes long time on android studio.In eclipse it doesnt take 4 - 5 seconds, and the app is on my phone device. whereas android studio everytime i run, it takes 2 - 3 mins gradle build running.Its crazy slow. And next to disaster.

My build gradle file

> ```
>  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>   android {
> compileSdkVersion 23
> buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
> defaultConfig {
>     applicationId "com.netvariant.heinz"
>     minSdkVersion 14
>     targetSdkVersion 22
>     multiDexEnabled true
>     versionCode 1
>     versionName "1.1"
> }
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         minifyEnabled false
>         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>     }
> }
> packagingOptions {
>     exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
>     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
>     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
>     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
>     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
> }
> sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/anim'] } }}
> dependencies {
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
> }
> ```

Comment: Please follow this link, Android Studio is Updated and provide instant run 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

Comment: Did you try creating new project and checking if it would also take so long to compile? Maybe it's something with your installation.

Comment: Try Power save mode from file menu last second option not build gradle each time but fast some what

Comment: I have android studio 1.5.1 build on dcember 2015

Comment: Mr. User, Yes you are right. I was the victim of the above issue for long time and keep me away from using android studio. Would you mine to share your system specification so that i could comment in a better way

Comment: unfortunately android studio is slower than eclipse in building, but u can speed it by using it in offline mode, by going into settings->build,execution,deployment->buid tools->gradle->offline work and select it